# Looking for help on an ancient history series

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Many, many years ago I read a series, think it was a trilogy, about auras. the paperbacks had an illustration on the cover in the form of a teardrop, with the teardrop on each cover being a different color.

Can anybody help?

Comment: This is incredibly vague. Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can [edit] in any more details? Thanks.

Comment: Also, there is nothing in your questions that would justify the use of the [tag:aliens] tag

Answer (score 3):

This may be the *Cluster* trilogy by Piers Anthony (five books... Piers Anthony).  The books follow "high aura" individuals as they fight an extragalactic enemy -- but do it in other bodies than their own, after their Kirlian auras are transferred to other worlds.

[image: Book Cover - Cluster] [image: Book Cover - Chaining the Lady] [image: Book Cover - Kirlian Quest] [image: Book Cover - Thousandstar] [image: Book Cover - Viscous Circle]

> As Cluster opens, the alien envoy Pnotl of Sphere Knyfh seeks help from Sphere Sol in a shared galactic‑level crisis: Galaxy Andromeda has discovered the secret of energy transfer and intends to use it to steal the basic energy of the Milky Way Galaxy. Knyfh offers the secret of aura transfer on the understanding that Sphere Sol will spread the technology to help create a galactic coalition to find and defeat agents of Andromeda. Sol's highest‑Kirlian individual is Flint, a green‑skinned native of Outworld, who has a Kirlian aura of two hundred, an eidetic memory (useful for memorizing the complex equations of Kirlian transfer that he will need to communicate to other spheres). He has extraordinary intelligence and is highly adaptable

The original three books covers at one point all shared a cube motif that could be remembered as a teardrop.

[image: Cluster cover from ISFDB]
[image: Chaining the Lady cover from ISFDB]
[image: Kirlian Quest cover from ISFDB]

Comment: Cluster is a trilogy, he just stuck two extra books on...because he can't seem to not do that sometimes.  Cluster is also related to the Tarot "trilogy" (3 books but meant as a single one) and _But What of Earth?_...sort of.  _But What of Earth?_ has a weird history as a novel.

Comment: @eshier I read all of these when they first came out.  Sadly, this was about the time Anthony's writing started going downhill, probably not a coincidence that he'd discovered about then that he could sell literally anything before he'd even written it.  This series was good, *Tarot* books not quite as good, and the ones after went noticeably downhill (especially the dozens of Xanth books).  He did write a bunch of trilogies longer than three books -- he once wrote it was because SF writers can't count.